# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' keeps coming up what do i do?

Tags: validation

If((Grade__c < 0 OR Grade__c > 100), true, false)

i dont see where im missing anything but it keeps giving me this error

Answer (score 2):

OR uses the function syntax:

```
OR(A, B)
```

While `||` would be used as you've done here:

```
IF(A || B, true, false)
```

Note that you don't need to use an IF statement here, as OR/|| already returns true/false values:

```
Grade__c < 0 || Grade__c > 100
```